# Cant connect to socket io server on cpanel https

Tags: node.js, socket.io, devops

i installed whm on server and created 2 hosts

1 . app.example.com
2 . socket.example.com

i got my laravel application on app.example.com
and im trying to create socket server on socket.example.com

Socket server
hosted on socket.example.com

```
const app = require("express")();

const fs = require("fs")
const https = require("https")
const https_server = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./server.cert')
},app);


const options = {
    cors : {
        origin : "*"
    }
};
const io = require("socket.io")(https_server, options);

io.on("connection", socket => { /* ... */ });

https_server.listen(8001);
```

client
hosted on app.example.com

```
<script>
const socket = io("https://socket.example.com:8001",{
        secure: true ,
    }) ;

    socket.on("connect",() => {
        console.log("connected")
    })

    socket.on("message",( e ) => {
        console.log( e )
    })
</script>
```

apache config
for reverse proxy

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
RewriteEngine On

# Everything else forwards as HTTP to the node app.
ProxyPass / https://127.0.0.1:8001/
ProxyPassReverse / https://127.0.0.1:8001/
```

i can connect to socket.example.com:8001 from localhost but  i cant connect from app.example.com

Error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://socket.example.com:8001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NcjrB8N' from origin 'https://app.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
connect_error due to xhr poll error
```

Comment: It is because `socket.example.com` and `app.example.com` shares same domain and `socket.example.com` does not allow Cross origin request so throwing error when you are trying to connect from localhost. try whitelisting localhost in `socket.example.com's` virtual host.

Comment: @Hrishi 
tnx  , 
i should edit /etc/hosts as root and add ```127.0.0.1 test.example.com``` ? why test ?

Comment: Checkout the ans below.  Instead of `test.example.com` you can create virtual host with any sub-domain like `local.example.com` just the domain should be same as socket server

Comment: @Hrishi it didnt work but tnx
i dont know why but when i added ```allowEIO3: true ``` to server and client it worked correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `socket.example.com` and `app.example.com` shares same domain and `socket.example.com` does not allow Cross origin request so throwing error when you are trying to connect from localhost. Try whitelisting localhost in `socket.example.com's` virtual host or try below solution.

Try this one.

In your virtual host file, change ServerName to `test.example.com` from `localhost` or create the virtualhost file like below if not present with name `test.example.com`.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.example.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/project/doc/root
    ErrorLog "var/log/error_log"
    CustomLog "var/log/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

And add below line at the bottom of file `/etc/hosts`

`127.0.0.1 test.example.com`

and then try to access your local application with `test.example.com` from browser.
It should work.